# Fatal error: Cannot use "self" when no class scope is active in /home/... on line 36

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

PHP 7.2 - WordPress 5.3.2

I'm trying to use a WP plugin from a couple of years ago but I get this error:

**Fatal error: Cannot use "self" when no class scope is active in /home/... on line 36**

Here is the code: functions.php

```
     <?php

    if (!function_exists('is_teatime_simple_error')) {

        /**
         * Checks if the object is an instance of a simple error
         * @param mixed $object The object to check against.
         * @return boolean Returns true if the object is a simple error
         */
        function is_teatime_simple_error($object) {
            if (is_a($object, 'Teatime_Simple_Error')) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

    }

    if (!function_exists('teatime_spintax')) {

        /**
         * Assembles a random spintax string.
         * @var str Text containing our {spintax|spuntext}
         * @return str Text with random spintax selections
         */
        function teatime_spintax($s) {
            preg_match('#{(.+?)}#is', $s, $m);
            if (empty($m))
                return $s;
            $t = $m[1];
            if (strpos($t, '{') !== false) {
                $t = substr($t, strrpos($t, '{') + 1);
            }
            $parts = explode("|", $t);
            $s = preg_replace("+{" . preg_quote($t) . "}+is", $parts[array_rand($parts)], $s, 1);
/** Error line 36 */  return self::spintax($s);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Isn't the error message pretty clear? You're using `self` while not being in the scope of a class.

Comment: Where is the `spintax()` function defined?

Comment: This code is not enough to find the problem. Share more. Also, can you define line 36 for example: Put a comment before it and write this is the line indicated in the error code

Comment: Could you please show more code?